# Unable to translate a term inside a Qweb condition in Odoo 10. How to do this?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I'm trying to translate a specific term which appears in a Qweb report, but its behaviour is very different from expected.

If you install the standard `sale` module in Odoo 10, take a look at its sale order report (XML ID = `report_saleorder_document`). Its code is in the `report` folder, file `sale_report_templates.xml`. You'll find the following line:

```
<td><span t-esc="amount_by_group[0] or 'Taxes'"/></td>
```

As you can see, there is a literal string, *Taxes*, which must be translated if you choose a language different from English. Try to translate the word to a language which hasn't translated it yet.

In my case, I'm trying to translate the term to Galician, in which the translation of *Taxes* was empty:

```
#. module: sale
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:sale.field_sale_order_amount_tax
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:sale.field_sale_order_line_price_tax
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:sale.field_sale_order_line_tax_id
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:sale.report_invoice_layouted
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:sale.report_saleorder_document
msgid "Taxes"
msgstr "Impostos"
```

But after restarting the service, updating the `sale` module, loading the Galician translation overwriting terms, synchronizing the terms, updating the browser, removing its cookies, and even updating `base` module, nothing happened.

Then I made the following query in PostgreSQL:

> SELECT id, lang, src, name, module, value, res_id FROM ir_translation WHERE src='Taxes' AND lang='gl_ES' ORDER BY id DESC;

```
   id   | lang  |  src  |               name                |  module  |    value    | res_id 
--------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+----------+-------------+--------
 123634 | gl_ES | Taxes | account.account.tag,applicability | account  | Taxes       |      0
 121625 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Taxes       |    364
 121624 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Taxes       |    428
 121619 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Taxes       |    414
 121618 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Taxes       |    415
 121617 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Taxes       |    441
 120817 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.menu,name                   | account  | Taxes       |    108
 113387 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | account  | Taxes       |   2878
 113385 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | account  | Taxes       |   2700
 111845 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.actions.act_window,name        | account  | Taxes       |    158
 111431 | gl_ES | Taxes | account.tax.group,name            | account  | Taxes       |      1
  47094 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Taxes       |    430
  46953 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | purchase | Impostos    |    746
  46952 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | purchase | Impostos    |   5045
  46951 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | purchase | Impostos    |   4992
  45544 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | sale     | Impostos    |    554
  45543 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | sale     | Impostos    |    556
  45542 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | sale     | Impostos    |   4128
  45541 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | sale     | Impostos    |   4120
  45540 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | sale     | Impostos    |   4085
(20 rows)
```

And I realized that the problem is that may be I had to translate the `account` module too (which I didn't understand because the term is in `sale` module), so I went to the Galician translation file of `account` module and updated it:

```
#. module: account
#: selection:account.account.tag,applicability:0
#: model:account.tax.group,name:account.tax_group_taxes
#: model:ir.actions.act_window,name:account.action_tax_form
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:account.field_account_invoice_line_invoice_line_tax_ids
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:account.field_account_move_line_tax_ids
#: model:ir.ui.menu,name:account.menu_action_tax_form
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:account.account_planner
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:account.invoice_form
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:account.invoice_supplier_form
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:account.report_invoice_document
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:account.view_account_config_settings
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:account.view_move_line_form
msgid "Taxes"
msgstr "Impostos"
```

But same problem, so I did the same query again and the result was this:

```
   id   | lang  |  src  |               name                |  module  |    value    | res_id 
--------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+----------+-------------+--------
 123634 | gl_ES | Taxes | account.account.tag,applicability | account  | Impostos    |      0
 121625 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Impostos    |    364
 121624 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Impostos    |    428
 121619 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Impostos    |    414
 121618 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Impostos    |    415
 121617 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Impostos    |    441
 120817 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.menu,name                   | account  | Impostos    |    108
 113387 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | account  | Impostos    |   2878
 113385 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | account  | Impostos    |   2700
 111845 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.actions.act_window,name        | account  | Impostos    |    158
 111431 | gl_ES | Taxes | account.tax.group,name            | account  | Taxes       |      1
  47094 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | account  | Impostos    |    430
  46953 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | purchase | Impostos    |    746
  46952 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | purchase | Impostos    |   5045
  46951 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | purchase | Impostos    |   4992
  45544 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | sale     | Impostos    |    554
  45543 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.ui.view,arch_db                | sale     | Impostos    |    556
  45542 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | sale     | Impostos    |   4128
  45541 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | sale     | Impostos    |   4120
  45540 | gl_ES | Taxes | ir.model.fields,field_description | sale     | Impostos    |   4085
(20 rows)
```

So I thought that the problem was this translation:

```
111431 | gl_ES | Taxes | account.tax.group,name            | account  | Taxes
```

And it is. If I modify this translation through a query in PostgreSQL, then when I print the sale order report, I can see the word translated to Galician.

But my question is: **what I have to do to translate that term through PO files and without executing a query?**

It's annoying as in some languages like Spanish the term is well translated through PO files... I think that this problem is easy to replicate, so I'll appreciate a lot if anyone tries it, understands what is happening and can explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem you've described and it does seem to be a bit surprising.

No matter what I tried, I was not able to get specifically that term updated by changing the `gl.po` file, nor by creating my own `gl.po` file. I *was* able to update other terms through that method, which suggests this might be a bug with that specific term for some reason.

Having said that, you *can* update the term manually through the user interface.

1. Activate the Developer Mode
2. Go to **Settings > Translations > Application Terms > Translated Terms**
3. Search:

   - **Source Term** = Taxes
   - **Translated Field** = account.tax.group,name
4. Update the **Translation Value** to *Impostos* (or whatever you prefer)

---

If you specifically need an automatic way to handle this and can't rely on a manual process, then you could modify the way that `_get_tax_amount_by_group` works.

```
@api.multi
def _get_tax_amount_by_group(self):
    ...
    from openerp.tools.translate import translate
    res = map(lambda l: (translate(self._cr, 'ir.ui.view,arch_db', 'model', self.partner_id.lang, l[0].name), l[1]), res)
    ...
```